# Completion blocks for sequences of concurrent SKActions in nested "for" loops?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to run a set of SKActions in a "for" loop, as in the code below. The sequence should run like this:

For the 1st superNode...

1. Run openingAction on all child subNodes concurrently; WHEN DONE...
2. Run variableDurationActions on all child spriteNodes concurrently; WHEN DONE...
3. Run closingAction on all child subNodes concurrently, AND AT THE SAME TIME...

For the 2nd superNode...

3. Run openingAction on all child subNodes concurrently; WHEN DONE...

And this three-step process repeats for each superNode.

The first problem is that, although I could write a closure to wait for one action to complete before starting another, I don't know how to go about doing so for several concurrent actions across "for" loops. This problem happens between Steps 1 and 2, and Steps 2 and 3. Between 2 and 3 it's even worse, because the durations of the actions at Step 2 can vary a lot.

The second problem is that I don't know how to write a completion handler, or some equivalent, to make closingAction and next iteration of openingAction run concurrently, but before the variableDurationActions in the next iteration.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with SpriteKit's tools? Or should I use dispatch groups instead? I'm looking for elegant solutions, because my code is complicated enough as it is.

```
for superNode in scene.children {

    for subNode in superNode.children {

        // All openingActions should run first
        subNode.run(openingAction)

            for spriteNode in subNode.children {

                // These variableDurationActions should run concurrently, second
                spriteNode.run(variableDurationAction)
            }

        // All closingActions should run third AND
        // concurrently with the openingActions in the next iteration
        subNode.run(closingAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you missing brackets before your third for loop?

Comment: you just need to add a wait duration for the difference of your longest variableDuration,  so if your longest is 2 second, and your shortest is 1 second, then you need the shortest to just wait 1 second

Comment: Thanks, @Knight0fDragon, for the remarks. I just removed the extra closing brace. While stripping out details and an attempt at implementing a completion handler, I missed it.

Comment: About adding wait actions, since there can be hundreds of spriteNodes with variableDurationActions per subNode, and selecting just the longest running one is awkward, I didn't want to take that tack. But on a more general note, how would timers be able to handle the increasing times of the "for" loops?

Although I thought at first dispatch groups were overkill, they are looking more and more like the way to go.

Comment: no... isnt your second for loop suppose to run on the completion of open action

Comment: Also, what do you mean you dont want to take that approach?  You already have 100s of actions running, and how is selecting the longest awkward?  It is literally what you said you wanted to do.  You want all closing actions to fire at the same time,  you cant do that till the longest action finishes

Comment: is this what your timeline should look like?  https://imgur.com/a/cP7eJoL

Comment: • The "for spriteNode . . ." loop is supposed to run on completion of all openingActions.

• The reason it would be awkward to pick the spriteNode with the longest running variableDurationAction is that I don't want to hard-code that in, because what might be the longest running one now might not be in the future (e.g., if I partially randomized durations).

• About your scene editor snapshot, it's the first time I've ever seen it. I didn't even know it existed until now. If I'm interpreting it correctly, it's not quite right. The second "moves" act on the children of those in the first….

Comment: Ill update the timeline for you, wasnt really worries about that part lol but ill update it to get a clear understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately came up with a solution by separating the temporally distinct processing steps, creating a dispatch group with two check points, and having the main function (at the bottom, below) iterate through the superNodes by calling itself.

It seems a little clumsy to me, but here's how it looks:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

// Step 1
func runOpeningActions() {
    for subNode in superNode.children {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        // All openingActions should run concurrently, first
        subNode.run(openingAction) { 
            dispatchGroup.leave() 
        }
    }
}

// Step 2
func runVariableDurationActions {
    for subNode in superNode.children {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        for spriteNode in subNode.children {
            // These variableDurationActions should run concurrently, second
            spriteNode.run(variableDurationAction) {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}

// Step 3 – to run concurrently with the next Step 1
func runClosingActions() {
    for subNode in superNode.children {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        // All closingActions should run concurrently, third AND
        // concurrently with the openingActions in the next iteration
        subNode.run(closingAction) { 
            dispatchGroup.leave() 
        }
    }
}

var nodeIndex = 0

// Main function – iterates over Steps 1, 2, and 3
func runAllActions() {
    let superNode = scene.children[nodeIndex]
    runOpeningActions()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        runVariableDurationActions()
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            runClosingActions()
            nodeIndex += 1
            if nodeIndex < scene.children.count {
                runAnimation()
            } else {
                // No more superNodes to process; leave the function
            }
        }
    }
}

// Main function call
runAllActions()
```